# firebase API key exposed in flutter's web index.html file

Tags: flutter, firebase, security, api-key

I deployed my web app on Firebase by adding a JS script to my index.html file. The script contained my project's API key.

Now when the user right-clicks on the website and selects the "view page source" option, they have access to the API key.

Does anyone know how to fix this?

The script looks like this (I have replaced the sensitive information with asterisks):

```
<script type="module">
    // Import the functions you need from the SDKs you need
    import { initializeApp } from "https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/10.5.0/firebase-app.js";
    import { getAnalytics } from "https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/10.5.0/firebase-analytics.js";
    // TODO: Add SDKs for Firebase products that you want to use
    // https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup#available-libraries

    // Your web app's Firebase configuration
    // For Firebase JS SDK v7.20.0 and later, measurementId is optional
    const firebaseConfig = {
      apiKey: "**********************************",
      authDomain: "*******************",
      projectId: "********",
      storageBucket: "**********",
      messagingSenderId: "********",
      appId: "**************************",
      measurementId: "************"
    };

    // Initialize Firebase
    const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
    const analytics = getAnalytics(app);
  </script>
```

I tried working with the firebase CLI to add some variables that are used for authentication at the cloud level (purely based off of a suggestion from ChatGPT), but that didn't seem to work at all.

Comment: This is expected. Firebase configuration data is not a secret, and is in fact necessary in order for your app to be able to access Firebase's services on the server. See the question I linked for full details.